# Cannot reuse socket stream for different data type? (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server

I have a simple client server socket setup.

1. Server accepts client connection.
2. Server sends an object over the socket.
3. Server does some calculations.
4. Over the same socket, server sends back a boolean value for whether the calculations were correct. (this is where the thread freezes)

such that:

Server.java.

```
connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

// first sends the object
objectStream.writeObject(testObject);

objectStream.flush(); // i dont really know
objectStream.reset();

// some code

// returns if the code was succesful
objectStream.writeBoolean(true);
```

Client.java

```
    // initial object sent over the socket
    object  = (TestObject) in.readObject();
    System.out.println(object.toString());

    // true if the server test was correct (thread freezes here)
    boolean b  = in.readBoolean();
    System.out.println("Test: " +b);
    clientSocket.close();
```

This is supposed to first return the 'testObject' print it's data to the screen and then return true and also print that to the screen.

However, it is able to do the first part, but freezes the thread at in.readBoolean(); I understand that streams hold a header holding data about the bytes sent, so my assumption was to call out.reset(); or out.flush(); but neither of these seem to do anything. I'm sure its a simple answer, but i can't find any examples of my exact problem.

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe `flush` again after writing the boolean value?

Comment: heh, i knew itd be easy, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ahem.

Put flush after writeBoolean();